# Unable to load the mojo 'war' in the plugin

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I have configured all the dependencies in my `pom.xml` through maven. When i give the command build I get the following error

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
> org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.4:war (default-war) on
> project nwt_thp_api_br_be-web: Execution default-war of goal
> org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.4:war failed: Unable to
> load the mojo 'war' in the plugin
> 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.4' due to an API
> incompatibility:
> org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException:
> null

How can I resolve this?

Comment: You should use a more recent version of maven-war-plugin  https://maven.apache.org/plugins/

Comment: Agree with khmarbaise, you should upgrade your "war-plugin" and keep a recent version of Java. In my case (with Java 17) I switched from maven-war-plugin 2.1.1 to 3.3.2 and it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have fixed: I changed the version of JDK to 1.8 and pointed correctly to settings.xml. After that, I made a maven update and then maven build and it worked.